# How to remove space from start of a php file?

Tags: php

Have a PHP file which is making RSS feeds it is giving error because of the space appending before the output XML file. I have checked the code and the variable containing the variable `$s` which is making XML file does not have any white space before it.

```
<?php

  header("Content-Type: text/xml; encoding=UTF-8");
  $s = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><rss version='2.0'><channel>"; 
 echo ltrim($s);

 foreach($this->results as $row)
  {
     $title=$row->name;
     $description=$row->description;  
     echo "<item><title>$title</title><link>$link</link><description>$description</description></item>"; 
  } 
  echo "</channel></rss>"; 

?>
```

[image]

Comment: Check if there is any spaces before <?php and after ?>  - in the PHP file which generated the feed.

Comment: ?> its the file ending

Comment: Stop using `?>` at the file ending. It does not make any sense and only causes problems. Just remove it.

Comment: even after removing it icode does not work

Comment: Use a `hexeditor` to examine the output and find out what character exactly it is that precedes the xml content. That can help you to narrow down your search.

Comment: Without seeing your actual code we can hardly do anything

Comment: i have posted my code here @HankyPanky

Comment: use this and try echo trim($s);

Comment: Is that your file's ***exact*** content? Just copy paste your file as it is. Not a *version* of it

Comment: i copy pasted it only

Comment: There is something missing that you haven't given us. I copied your code above and it outputs as expected. I would not usually ask, because it is less efficient, but in this case it may help. Could you take a screenshot of your development environment as you are looking at the file?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure no white space before `<?php`

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/xml; encoding=UTF-8");
$s = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><rss version='2.0'><channel>"; 
echo ltrim($s);

foreach($this->results as $row)
{
$title=$row->name;
$description=$row->description;  
echo "<item><title>$title</title><link>$link</link><description>$description</description></item>"; 
} 

echo "</channel></rss>"; 

?>
```